# How to use "criteria" methods in Mongoid with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, criteria

I'd like to use the Mongoid criteria methods ( http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html ).  I have a model named College. In the College controller:

```
def index
  @colleges = College.all_of(:sat_rmw.gt => 1200, :in_state_tuition.lt => 12000)
end
```

This generates the error:

> undefined method `all_of' for College:Class

Am I supposed to use criteria in the College Model as opposed to the Controller?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same problem too (might be a bug in the current version, but I can't find any tickets regarding it). Whatever the case, you can replicate this behaviour using the `where` and `and` methods instead. Your query above would become:

```
@colleges = College.where(:sat_rmw.gt => 1200).and(:in_state_tuition.lt => 12000)
```

Comment: I've noticed that 'where' works, but now I'm really curious why the criteria methods aren't working.  I'm using Rails 3.0.9 and Mongoid 2.2 - how about you? (I'm not using Rails 3.1 because it seems like lots of plugins weren't working with it, and I'm using Mongoid 2.2 because 2.3 didn't seem to work with Rails 3.0.9).

Comment: I just did a quick test in 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3. It would seem that `all_of` was added in 2.3 - which is why you're having trouble. Personally, I find the where().and() criteria methods much more readable.